# Find the given limit of $S$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find the given limit  of $S$ ?
>
> $$S=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}  \left (\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{ n+1}} { 1} +\frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}{ n+1}} { 2} +  + ....+ \frac{\sin \frac{n\pi}{ n+1}} { n} \right )$$

## My attempt :

i construct  modified the  given series

$\frac{\pi}{ n+1}\left (\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{ n+1}} { \frac{1\pi}{ n+1}} +\frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}{ n+1}} { \frac{2\pi}{ n+1}} + ... + ....+ \frac{\sin \frac{n\pi}{ n+1}} { \frac{n\pi}{ n+1}} \right )$

After that im not able to proceed further

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: I don't think that there is a much nicer closed form. What makes you believe that?

Comment: maybe Taylor expansion will work

Comment: The accepted answer that this diverges is incorrect.

Comment: okss  ...@RRL.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it as a Riemann sum:

$$S_n=\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{ n+1}} { 1} +\frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}{ n+1}} { 2} +  + ....+ \frac{\sin \frac{n\pi}{ n+1}} { n}$$ $$= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin\frac{i\pi}{ n+1}}{\frac{i}{n+1}}\frac{1}{n+1} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_0^1\frac{\sin \pi x}{x}dx = Si(\pi)\approx 1.852$$

Answer (score 2):

The limit exists and is bounded above as

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin  \left( \frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right) \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{\pi}{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1} \pi = \pi$$

Answer (score 1):

This converges to:

$$Si(\pi) = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{sin(x)}{x} dx \approx 1.851937051982468 $$

by numerical analysis.

HTH